# What is the implementation for FirebaseRecylerOptions (Not FirebaseRecylerAdapter)

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio

I been search for implementation for FirebaseRecylerOptions. I wasn't able to find it. I was able to find FirebaseRecylerAdapter but I did not found FirebaseRecylerOptions. I have looked almost everywhere. But I did not found it. If you have the implementation can you please write it down below because I cannot find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On dependencies add this:     compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'

On your import add this: import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that with recyclerview and add onclick listener in each views.